# multiple fragment in switch-case

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

i'm trying to add new fragment in the switch case block. I used the same code for add inbox fragment. But i have this error:

> Error:(94, 45) error: no suitable method found for
>   replace(int,ProfileFragment) method
>   FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment,String) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) method
>   FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment) is not applicable (actual
>   argument ProfileFragment cannot be converted to Fragment by method
>   invocation conversion)

I think that the problem is related to the library but i don't know how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
case R.id.home:
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, home);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    return true;
case R.id.profilo:
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Profilo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ProfileFragment profilo = new ProfileFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.frame, profilo);
    fragmentTransaction1.commit();
    return true;
```

Please help me!

Comment: check the imports of your Fragment related classes. Everything has to be either from the support library or from the native support

Answer (score 0):

Check the import in your fragment class that whether you have imported

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

or

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

In your case you should import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. Anyway i don't fix the problem. Now i post all the mainactivity

http://pastebin.com/HFwZ4qvD

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because you have imported the fragments from android.app.fragment. Try to import from the support library. (import android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

Comment: Thanks i solved. The problem was in a fragment :S

Another question please. How can i set a specific fragment as default when i start the app?

Comment: Just add a default case to your switch.